# 3d to 2d conversion of text files and autmatically pasting /loading .m file in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, textbox

**Update 1**:

I have **GP_Height data** in text file. This text file consist on **3D array**. Its complete description is as fellow

**[t][x][y], Value1 , Value2,..... , value 8**

(1) [t] is the time which remains [0] in text file

(2) [x] is **pressure level** index varies [0] to [16] : It is corresponding to pressure levels which are [1000.0, 925.0, 850.0, 700.0, 600.0, 500.0, 400.0, 300.0, 250.0, 200.0, 150.0, 100.0, 70.0, 50.0, 30.0, 20.0, 10.0]

(3) [y] is the latitude index varies from [0] to [8] :It is corresponding to latitude index which are [37.5, 35.0, 32.5, 30.0, 27.5, 25.0, 22.5, 20.0]

(4) Value1,value2...value8 :Are GP_height values corresponding to longitude index  [60.0, 62.5, 65.0, 67.5, 70.0, 72.5, 75.0, 77.5]

**Now**

[0][0][0] , value1,.... ,value8 are 8 values of tGP_height corresponding to time 0, pressure level 1000 , latitude 20.0 with corresponding to longitude index.

and soon on such pattern

I want to export 17 text files with output_no.txt(where no is from 0 to 16) such that first column is latitude , second column is longitude and third column consist on GP_height value at this lat, lon

I try this , but not sure what is going on.(producing wrong output. Missing GP_height)

```
pressures = [1000, 925, 850, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, 70, 50, 30, 20, 15, 10, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1.5, 1] ;

   % - Read source file.
   fSpec = ['[%f][%f][%f]', repmat( ', %f', 1, 8 )] ;
   data  = textscan( fileread( 'modified.New Text Document.txt' ), fSpec ) ;
%New Text Document
   % - Extract/gather all x and gp values. 
   X  = data{1} ;
   GP = horzcat( data{3:end} ) ;

   % - Build arrays of lon/lat which correspond to GP.
   [lon, lat] = meshgrid( 60:2.5:77.5, 20:2.5:37.5) ;

   % - Iterate through pressure IDs and process.
   for x = 0 : 23
      % Get relevant block of GP (the one thta corresponds to current p).
      gp = GP(X==x,:) ;
      % Build 3 columns data array.
      data = [reshape(lat.',[],1), reshape(lon.',[],1), reshape(gp.',[],1)].' ;
      % Verbose.
      fprintf( 'Export for pressure ID %d -> p=%.1fhpa.\n', x, pressures(x+1) ) ;
      % Export.
      fId = fopen( sprintf( 'Output_%d.txt', x), 'w' ) ;
      fprintf( fId, 'latitude\tlongitude\tGP_height\r\n' ) ;
      fprintf( fId, '%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\r\n', data(:) ) ;
      fclose( fId ) ;
   end
```

**My data in text file** looks like this

```
[0][0][0], 4.2099915, 4.5599976, 4.2599945, 3.2299957, 2.0599976, 1.5800018, 1.5999908, 1.8699951

[0][0][1], 6.319992, 6.6799927, 5.349991, 3.3499908, 2.369995, 2.1900024, 1.9900055, 2.1900024

[0][0][2], 8.119995, 8.059998, 5.3399963, 2.25, 2.2200012, 2.300003, 1.5800018, 1.9199982

[0][0][3], 7.9799957, 7.3099976, 4.0399933, 1.8999939, 3.2599945, 3.130005, 2.1600037, 2.7599945

[0][0][4], 5.1600037, 4.7599945, 4.029999, 4.4599915, 4.9599915, 4.099991, 3.0899963, 3.4299927

[0][0][5], 2.5, 4.669998, 6.220001, 6.4299927, 5.5599976, 4.2400055, 3.3399963, 3.1100006

[0][0][6], 5.9299927, 7.6100006, 8.330002, 7.6600037, 6.1399994, 4.699997, 3.869995, 3.130005

[0][0][7], 9.429993, 10.149994, 9.959991, 8.809998, 7.2400055, 5.869995, 4.779999, 3.7899933

[0][1][0], 5.6900024, 6.069992, 5.4799957, 4.0200043, 2.380005, 1.5899963, 1.5299988, 1.800003

[0][1][1], 7.1600037, 7.5899963, 6.0399933, 3.7400055, 2.4199982, 2.0599976, 1.8699951, 2.2099915

[0][1][2], 8.179993, 8.119995, 5.1600037, 2.0, 2.1600037, 2.1900024, 1.6900024, 2.1600037

[0][1][3], 7.75, 7.1799927, 3.8099976, 2.6600037, 4.1600037, 3.800003, 3.1799927, 3.6699982

[0][1][4], 5.7700043, 5.5, 4.369995, 5.4299927, 6.4900055, 5.669998, 4.970001, 5.149994

[0][1][5], 3.5399933, 4.7899933, 5.599991, 6.7400055, 7.399994, 6.8099976, 6.029999, 5.3099976

[0][1][6], 4.599991, 6.3099976, 7.4299927, 8.069992, 8.270004, 7.919998, 7.2299957, 6.099991

[0][1][7], 9.020004, 10.349991, 11.039993, 10.860001, 10.160004, 9.339996, 8.419998, 7.419998

[0][2][0], 6.8399963, 7.2700043, 6.220001, 4.4100037, 2.7099915, 1.7599945, 1.4700012, 1.8099976

[0][2][1], 9.300003, 9.399994, 7.0599976, 4.029999, 2.3399963, 1.7599945, 1.7200012, 2.149994

[0][2][2], 10.539993, 9.940002, 5.970001, 1.9299927, 2.149994, 2.0399933, 1.9599915, 2.7099915

[0][2][3], 9.649994, 8.970001, 4.9299927, 3.0599976, 4.3899994, 3.7099915, 3.5599976, 4.319992

[0][2][4], 7.569992, 7.569992, 5.25, 4.419998, 5.169998, 4.300003, 4.699997, 5.5399933

[0][2][5], 4.869995, 5.669998, 4.7400055, 4.130005, 4.720001, 4.580002, 5.399994, 6.1399994

[0][2][6], 2.9100037, 4.0, 4.2099915, 4.349991, 5.099991, 5.869995, 6.880005, 7.419998

[0][2][7], 3.2099915, 4.599991, 6.069992, 7.0200043, 7.9900055, 9.069992, 9.800003, 9.75

[0][3][0], 7.369995, 6.1900024, 4.1399994, 2.5800018, 1.8099976, 1.550003, 2.199997, 3.4799957

[0][3][1], 8.639999, 6.830002, 4.169998, 2.4599915, 1.7799988, 1.7400055, 1.949997, 2.2299957

[0][3][2], 9.229996, 6.419998, 3.0099945, 1.6699982, 1.7899933, 2.399994, 3.0800018, 3.319992

[0][3][3], 8.559998, 5.75, 2.8099976, 2.319992, 2.4299927, 3.069992, 3.4900055, 3.7299957

[0][3][4], 7.819992, 6.2899933, 3.9199982, 2.9299927, 3.9199982, 5.0899963, 5.1399994, 4.8099976

[0][3][5], 7.569992, 7.2400055, 5.7099915, 5.0099945, 5.599991, 5.849991, 5.330002, 5.0200043

[0][3][6], 8.229996, 8.470001, 7.25, 5.5599976, 4.279999, 4.0899963, 4.25, 4.199997

[0][3][7], 8.319992, 7.6600037, 5.8099976, 4.029999, 4.4400024, 5.819992, 6.630005, 6.550003

[0][4][0], 7.4400024, 4.949997, 4.099991, 4.3600006, 3.8099976, 2.5200043, 1.8899994, 2.0999908

[0][4][1], 8.050003, 4.0899963, 3.0099945, 3.0299988, 2.8300018, 2.649994, 2.369995, 2.069992

[0][4][2], 8.599991, 4.220001, 3.130005, 2.9199982, 2.8600006, 3.1799927, 3.25, 3.0899963

[0][4][3], 9.110001, 5.2099915, 3.6699982, 2.5, 2.9299927, 3.8300018, 3.5599976, 3.25

[0][4][4], 9.069992, 5.949997, 3.5599976, 3.399994, 5.119995, 6.1900024, 5.819992, 5.4799957

[0][4][5], 8.470001, 6.7400055, 5.2700043, 5.75, 6.6799927, 6.7299957, 6.130005, 5.8899994

[0][4][6], 8.959991, 8.389999, 7.2099915, 6.1399994, 5.029999, 4.319992, 3.9400024, 3.8300018

[0][4][7], 9.389999, 8.319992, 6.3899994, 4.4599915, 3.6699982, 4.300003, 4.7899933, 5.0

[0][5][0], 8.069992, 6.449997, 7.2099915, 8.209991, 8.119995, 7.1100006, 6.0, 5.1799927

[0][5][1], 7.7400055, 5.4100037, 6.1799927, 7.149994, 6.9599915, 5.9100037, 4.699997, 3.5

[0][5][2], 8.039993, 5.7099915, 5.869995, 5.9900055, 5.6600037, 4.7400055, 3.880005, 3.199997

[0][5][3], 8.419998, 6.050003, 4.9900055, 4.0899963, 3.800003, 3.4599915, 3.7700043, 4.130005

[0][5][4], 7.669998, 5.3399963, 3.7799988, 3.9199982, 5.029999, 5.279999, 5.3600006, 5.899994

[0][5][5], 6.2299957, 4.949997, 4.970001, 6.0200043, 6.569992, 6.319992, 6.0200043, 6.2299957

[0][5][6], 6.470001, 6.550003, 6.580002, 6.169998, 5.3399963, 4.8600006, 4.6600037, 4.8099976

[0][5][7], 7.550003, 7.0899963, 6.0599976, 4.699997, 3.699997, 3.369995, 3.4599915, 3.9199982

[0][6][0], 11.789993, 11.639999, 12.889999, 14.25, 14.860001, 14.830002, 14.589996, 14.209991

[0][6][1], 11.0, 11.089996, 12.410004, 13.419998, 13.479996, 12.720001, 11.699997, 10.479996

[0][6][2], 10.179993, 10.050003, 10.610001, 10.660004, 9.7400055, 8.459991, 7.3899994, 6.380005

[0][6][3], 8.729996, 7.9599915, 7.5, 6.7400055, 5.6600037, 4.849991, 4.849991, 5.1600037

[0][6][4], 6.399994, 5.2099915, 4.830002, 5.0899963, 5.6399994, 5.669998, 6.080002, 6.6600037

[0][6][5], 5.169998, 5.220001, 5.669998, 6.199997, 6.6100006, 6.649994, 6.6600037, 6.819992

[0][6][6], 6.399994, 6.8399963, 6.7299957, 6.130005, 5.75, 5.720001, 5.869995, 5.9900055

[0][6][7], 7.9400024, 7.279999, 6.25, 5.119995, 4.3600006, 4.2400055, 4.5899963, 5.0

[0][7][0], 20.410004, 21.959991, 24.220001, 25.98999, 26.699997, 26.5, 25.839996, 24.949997

[0][7][1], 19.330002, 20.690002, 22.050003, 22.490005, 21.869995, 20.589996, 19.130005, 17.539993

[0][7][2], 15.459991, 15.940002, 15.789993, 15.039993, 13.720001, 12.369995, 11.2400055, 9.880005

[0][7][3], 10.0099945, 9.610001, 8.860001, 8.139999, 7.599991, 7.279999, 7.25, 6.849991

[0][7][4], 6.2599945, 5.830002, 5.5599976, 5.75, 6.4599915, 7.2599945, 8.190002, 8.720001

[0][7][5], 5.9299927, 6.149994, 6.6100006, 7.380005, 7.919998, 8.449997, 9.059998, 9.449997

[0][7][6], 8.649994, 8.880005, 8.919998, 8.819992, 8.610001, 8.649994, 8.910004, 9.110001

[0][7][7], 11.5099945, 10.959991, 10.429993, 9.919998, 9.419998, 9.110001, 9.050003, 9.139999

[0][8][0], 24.789993, 27.080002, 29.869995, 31.839996, 32.47, 31.979996, 30.869995, 29.520004

[0][8][1], 22.029999, 23.880005, 25.339996, 25.720001, 25.009995, 23.630005, 21.979996, 20.279999

[0][8][2], 16.729996, 17.330002, 17.169998, 16.399994, 15.279999, 14.110001, 12.919998, 11.5

[0][8][3], 10.599991, 10.139999, 9.289993, 8.679993, 8.529999, 8.550003, 8.5099945, 8.0099945

[0][8][4], 6.7400055, 6.5099945, 6.199997, 6.4400024, 7.3099976, 8.559998, 9.809998, 10.4900055

[0][8][5], 6.7400055, 7.4299927, 8.220001, 8.9900055, 9.580002, 10.2599945, 11.169998, 11.910004

[0][8][6], 11.029999, 11.399994, 11.7599945, 11.819992, 11.599991, 11.440002, 11.649994, 12.139999

[0][8][7], 14.880005, 14.589996, 14.449997, 14.179993, 13.619995, 13.029999, 12.770004, 12.889999

[0][9][0], 26.399994, 29.069992, 32.190002, 34.410004, 35.229996, 34.75, 33.440002, 31.800003

[0][9][1], 22.39, 24.679993, 26.539993, 27.199997, 26.660004, 25.319992, 23.619995, 21.910004

[0][9][2], 16.440002, 17.679993, 18.11, 17.64, 16.690002, 15.580002, 14.2400055, 12.649994

[0][9][3], 10.410004, 10.589996, 10.410004, 10.130005, 10.179993, 10.279999, 9.819992, 9.0099945

[0][9][4], 7.699997, 7.669998, 7.5899963, 8.2400055, 9.729996, 11.199997, 12.179993, 12.589996

[0][9][5], 9.589996, 10.2400055, 10.849991, 11.4900055, 12.279999, 13.319992, 14.399994, 15.160004

[0][9][6], 14.899994, 15.289993, 15.349991, 15.169998, 15.039993, 15.270004, 15.839996, 16.470001

[0][9][7], 19.36, 19.289993, 19.080002, 18.720001, 18.300003, 18.059998, 18.089996, 18.309998

[0][10][0], 24.839996, 26.880005, 29.440002, 31.459991, 32.42, 32.339996, 31.520004, 30.270004

[0][10][1], 21.380005, 23.0, 24.569992, 25.220001, 24.740005, 23.470001, 21.880005, 20.490005

[0][10][2], 15.399994, 16.569992, 17.39, 17.199997, 16.039993, 14.610001, 13.209991, 12.029999

[0][10][3], 9.470001, 10.449997, 11.25, 11.279999, 10.869995, 10.440002, 9.970001, 9.5

[0][10][4], 9.199997, 10.160004, 11.080002, 12.0099945, 13.0, 13.809998, 14.130005, 13.929993

[0][10][5], 13.449997, 14.410004, 15.369995, 16.34999, 17.279999, 17.970001, 18.229996, 18.179993

[0][10][6], 19.209991, 19.789993, 20.309998, 20.869995, 21.369995, 21.64, 21.709991, 21.830002

[0][10][7], 24.75, 24.990005, 25.25, 25.64, 25.929993, 25.880005, 25.669998, 25.720001

[0][11][0], 16.009995, 17.209991, 18.529999, 19.449997, 19.789993, 19.679993, 19.36, 18.970001

[0][11][1], 12.940002, 14.130005, 15.080002, 15.169998, 14.479996, 13.449997, 12.699997, 12.440002

[0][11][2], 8.5099945, 9.699997, 10.459991, 10.169998, 9.279999, 8.270004, 7.830002, 7.9900055

[0][11][3], 7.470001, 8.270004, 9.110001, 9.399994, 9.209991, 8.880005, 8.529999, 8.800003

[0][11][4], 11.779999, 12.619995, 13.880005, 14.979996, 15.550003, 15.4900055, 15.149994, 15.199997

[0][11][5], 17.300003, 18.259995, 19.84999, 21.449997, 22.410004, 22.479996, 22.119995, 22.009995

[0][11][6], 21.910004, 23.09999, 24.89, 26.73999, 27.949997, 28.209991, 27.869995, 27.64

[0][11][7], 25.660004, 27.080002, 28.869995, 30.720001, 32.039993, 32.429993, 32.17, 31.949997

[0][12][0], 4.319992, 4.6799927, 5.069992, 5.4100037, 5.7099915, 6.050003, 6.1399994, 5.830002

[0][12][1], 3.7099915, 4.119995, 4.3600006, 4.4400024, 4.5, 4.7299957, 4.9599915, 5.0399933

[0][12][2], 4.330002, 4.419998, 4.5399933, 4.6799927, 4.7700043, 4.949997, 5.2599945, 5.699997

[0][12][3], 7.369995, 7.580002, 8.0, 8.399994, 8.589996, 8.610001, 8.720001, 9.0099945

[0][12][4], 12.800003, 13.160004, 13.649994, 13.919998, 13.869995, 13.690002, 13.660004, 13.929993

[0][12][5], 17.880005, 18.240005, 18.589996, 18.64, 18.459991, 18.369995, 18.660004, 19.300003

[0][12][6], 20.949997, 21.240005, 21.449997, 21.399994, 21.270004, 21.5, 22.240005, 23.279999

[0][12][7], 21.830002, 22.029999, 22.160004, 22.069992, 22.039993, 22.449997, 23.369995, 24.440002

[0][13][0], 4.6600037, 4.2899933, 4.0200043, 3.949997, 4.069992, 4.1900024, 4.1799927, 4.149994

[0][13][1], 6.3099976, 5.8899994, 5.4900055, 5.4100037, 5.699997, 6.130005, 6.5, 6.9100037

[0][13][2], 8.779999, 8.4900055, 8.099991, 8.0, 8.330002, 8.849991, 9.289993, 9.720001

[0][13][3], 11.970001, 11.839996, 11.520004, 11.380005, 11.630005, 12.039993, 12.289993, 12.369995

[0][13][4], 14.940002, 14.899994, 14.630005, 14.479996, 14.699997, 15.050003, 15.190002, 15.0099945

[0][13][5], 16.84999, 16.910004, 16.759995, 16.690002, 16.949997, 17.339996, 17.539993, 17.39

[0][13][6], 17.529999, 17.789993, 17.809998, 17.880005, 18.14, 18.459991, 18.59999, 18.520004

[0][13][7], 17.069992, 17.509995, 17.690002, 17.839996, 17.990005, 18.0, 17.800003, 17.61

[0][14][0], 10.309998, 10.199997, 10.160004, 10.199997, 10.330002, 10.440002, 10.419998, 10.149994

[0][14][1], 12.130005, 12.2400055, 12.360001, 12.410004, 12.470001, 12.599991, 12.720001, 12.679993

[0][14][2], 13.5099945, 13.860001, 14.110001, 14.110001, 14.020004, 14.110001, 14.429993, 14.770004

[0][14][3], 15.020004, 15.479996, 15.800003, 15.7400055, 15.529999, 15.529999, 15.929993, 16.529999

[0][14][4], 16.899994, 17.229996, 17.449997, 17.34999, 17.09999, 17.059998, 17.369995, 17.899994

[0][14][5], 18.410004, 18.440002, 18.380005, 18.160004, 17.959991, 18.009995, 18.289993, 18.61

[0][14][6], 18.399994, 18.209991, 17.819992, 17.369995, 17.199997, 17.470001, 17.929993, 18.209991

[0][14][7], 16.589996, 16.440002, 15.869995, 15.160004, 14.910004, 15.389999, 16.089996, 16.459991

[0][15][0], 13.270004, 13.25, 13.169998, 13.089996, 13.0099945, 12.889999, 12.699997, 12.520004

[0][15][1], 15.309998, 15.25, 14.970001, 14.800003, 14.860001, 15.0, 15.029999, 14.929993

[0][15][2], 16.740005, 16.61, 16.190002, 16.020004, 16.319992, 16.809998, 17.080002, 17.0

[0][15][3], 18.029999, 17.86, 17.429993, 17.319992, 17.789993, 18.440002, 18.729996, 18.509995

[0][15][4], 19.300003, 19.240005, 18.990005, 19.009995, 19.479996, 20.0, 20.069992, 19.61

[0][15][5], 19.919998, 20.11, 20.179993, 20.39, 20.779999, 21.020004, 20.839996, 20.279999

[0][15][6], 19.410004, 19.729996, 20.089996, 20.479996, 20.789993, 20.779999, 20.470001, 20.080002

[0][15][7], 17.970001, 18.169998, 18.589996, 19.119995, 19.410004, 19.209991, 18.800003, 18.630005

[0][16][0], 13.349991, 13.179993, 13.330002, 13.619995, 13.949997, 14.279999, 14.599991, 14.910004

[0][16][1], 15.099991, 15.309998, 15.9900055, 16.649994, 16.979996, 16.959991, 16.86, 16.970001

[0][16][2], 16.729996, 17.240005, 18.34999, 19.36, 19.729996, 19.520004, 19.220001, 19.199997

[0][16][3], 17.419998, 17.940002, 19.089996, 20.169998, 20.630005, 20.589996, 20.59999, 20.89

[0][16][4], 17.630005, 17.800003, 18.529999, 19.259995, 19.569992, 19.720001, 20.190002, 21.020004

[0][16][5], 18.550003, 18.36, 18.5, 18.64, 18.59999, 18.699997, 19.300003, 20.34999

[0][16][6], 20.25, 19.929993, 19.709991, 19.490005, 19.25, 19.279999, 19.759995, 20.520004

[0][16][7], 21.319992, 21.080002, 20.800003, 20.569992, 20.529999, 20.800003, 21.270004, 21.59999
```

I **want to export in each text file like(created from other data set)**

latitude   longitude   GP_height

```
22.500       60.500       16511.000
22.500       61.500       16531.000
22.500       62.500       16532.000
22.500       63.500       16533.000
22.500       64.500       16536.000
22.500       65.500       16530.000
22.500       66.500       16532.000
22.500       67.500       16530.000
22.500       68.500       16526.000
22.500       69.500       16544.000
22.500       70.500       16538.000
22.500       71.500       16498.000
22.500       72.500       16520.000
22.500       73.500       16520.000
22.500       74.500       16509.000
22.500       75.500       16464.000
22.500       76.500       16476.000
22.500       77.500       16489.000
22.500       78.500       16477.000
23.500       60.500       16516.000
23.500       61.500       16514.000
23.500       62.500       16524.000
23.500       63.500       16529.000
23.500       64.500       16526.000
23.500       65.500       16522.000
23.500       66.500       16518.000
23.500       67.500       16510.000
```

**UPDATE 2**

**I have saved this code as sorted_lat_split.m into drive of address**

```
E:\meta data\new\data _thesis\NCEP\winds_speed
```

In **winds_speed** folder there are further **30 folders** and in each of these 30 folder there are **12 folders inside**. I want to past this **'sorted_lat_split.m'** file in each of **12 folders** and want to run this in each folder.

Tell me is this possible to paste this code so that my time will be save?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another parsing problem, this one is much easier as you have the delimiter, the first thing you need to do is take out the first column (I named it C1) which contains 3 indexes that you need to look up:

```
fileID = fopen('test1.txt')
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f  %f  %f %f %f %f %f %f','delimiter',',');
parseC1 = cell2mat(cellfun(@(s)sscanf(s,'[%d]'),C{1},'UniformOutput',false));
reshapeC1 = reshape(parseC1,3,size(parseC1,1)/3)' +1; %//PLUS 1 because matlab indexing starts at 1 NOT 0
```

Now this generates the C1 as a matrix of N by 3 where N is the total number of lines.

This will allow you to match to your pressure and temp vectors easily, the last step is just to concatenate your matrix with your 8 valued matrix:

```
readVec = [pressures(reshapeC1(:,2)); latt(reshapeC1(:,3))]'
Values = [C{2} C{3} C{4} C{5} C{6} C{7} C{8} C{9}];
LongtValues = longt(round(Values))
FinalResult = [readVec LongtValues];
```

displaying the first row gives:

```
>>  1000  37.5000000000000  67.5000000000000    70  67.5000000000000    65  62.5000000000000    62.5000000000000    62.5000000000000    62.5000000000000
```

which correspond to pressure 1000, latitude 37.5, and 8 longitude values. As I am not sure where you got the Temperature, and how you want to format your longitude and latitude into a table, I am unable to proceed further.

```
restructure = repmat(FinalResult(:,2),1,size(FinalResult,2)-2)'
Result = [restructure(:) LongtValues(:)]
```

This line gives your longitude and latitude readings as you specified:

```
>>Result =        37.5                      67.5
                  37.5                      72.5
                  37.5                      77.5
.....
```

Becareful with the reshapeC1, as I added 1 to all the indexes, because Matlab indexing starts at 1 not 0 (as most other languages). I tested this and it parses fine for all your lines.

Comment: it is just the replica of my code. I want to remove error associated with my code. I want to extract 17 text files from this only text file. Such that first column is latitude and second is longitude and third one is temperature as i mentioned above in my question @GameOfThrows

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem This is not replica of your code, it does not use a for loop for example and temperature is not mentioned in your question

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem This is an entirely different question, please start a new question, also please accept the answer if it worked.